# How should I make only one checkbox be checked in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not very familiar in working with data binding in WPF. Please take a look at my code. I want to restrict user to make only one selection.

A more general question is: How should I avoid looping through the data source, as what I have done in handleChecked method? I believe I needn't loop through the ItemSource, but don't know how.

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TheProgram.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="News Chooser">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="newsChooser" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="newsCategory" Margin="10,8,10,5" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ComboBox Name="newsSrc" SelectionChanged="handleNewsSrcChange" Margin="10,5,10,8" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10,0,10,8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Name="newsStories" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="8*" Header="Headline" Binding="{Binding Path=heading}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Padding" Value="5" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Path=isIncluded, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="handleChecked" />
                            <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="handleChecked" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,10,0">
        <Button Click="handleSendButton" Height="30" Width="70">Send</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace TheProgram
{

class NewsSrcTableItm
{
    public string heading { get; set; }
    public NewsItem itm { get; set; }
    public bool isIncluded { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private List<NewsItem> includedList = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        setNewsSourceComboBox();

        this.includedList = new List<NewsItem>();

        initializeNewsTable();
    }

    private void setNewsSourceComboBox()
    {
        ComboBox cbx = (ComboBox)this.FindName("newsSrc");
        cbx.ItemsSource = MainWinClass.comboBoxList();
        cbx.SelectedIndex = 0;

        ComboBox cbx1 = (ComboBox)this.FindName("newsCategory");
        cbx1.ItemsSource = MainWinClass.categoryList();
        cbx1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void initializeNewsTable()
    {
        newsStories.ItemsSource = MainWinClass.initializeNewsSource();
    }


    public void handleChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cbx = this.FindName("newsCategory") as ComboBox;
        String theSelected = Regex.Replace(cbx.SelectedValue.ToString(), " ", String.Empty);
        String theNewsCategory = char.ToLower(theSelected[0]) + theSelected.Substring(1);
        foreach (var r in newsStories.ItemsSource)
        {
            NewsSrcTableItm itm = (NewsSrcTableItm)r;
            if (itm.isIncluded)
            {
                if (itm.itm.getCategory() == null)
                {
                    itm.itm.setCategory(theNewsCategory);
                }
                this.includedList.Add(itm.itm);
            }
        }
    }

    public void handleNewsSrcChange(object Sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ComboBox cb = this.FindName("newsSrc") as ComboBox;
        newsStories.ItemsSource = MainWinClass.changeSource(cb.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }

    public async void handleSendButton(object Sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        NewsItem itm = this.includedList[0];
        String category = itm.getCategory();
        String title = itm.getHeading();
        String extract = null;
        String content = null;
        String timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        NewsContentFetcher f = new NewsContentFetcher(itm.getUrl());
        List<String> theList = await f.getContent();
        extract = theList[0];
        foreach (String s in theList)
        {
            content += s;
        }
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var values = new Dictionary<String, String> 
        {
            { "category", category },
            { "title", title },
            { "extract", extract },
            { "content", content },
            { "timestamp", timestamp }
        };
        var theContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost/addNews.php", theContent).Result;
        int statusCode = (int)result.StatusCode;
        if (statusCode == 200)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Completed");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("failed");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Of course you need to iterate through the items one way or another if you want to check/uncheck them.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for response. But is there anyway to get the checked checkbox index directly so that i can modify the binded data given the index?

Comment: You mean in the handleChecked event handler? See my answer.

Comment: @mm8 thanks. That's what I mean. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

> But is there anyway to get the checked checkbox index directly so that i can modify the binded data given the index?

Try this:

```
public void handleChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = e.OriginalSender as CheckBox;
    NewsSrcTableItm itm = chk.DataContext as NewsSrcTableItm;

    //get index:
    var sourceCollection = newsStories.ItemsSource as IList<NewsSrcTableItm>;
    int index = sourceCollection.IndexOf(itm);
    //...
}
```

Comment: not work. NullPointerException in NewsSrcTableItm its = chk.DataContext as NewsSrcTableItm.

Comment: Is chk or item null?

Comment: chi is null.....

Comment: There is no "chi" in my code...

Comment: should be chk, sorry for the autocomplete

Comment: Ok, cast e.OriginalSource instead of sender. See my edited answer. Then it should work.